Loocv() error in R: unable to locate required distance matrix when using SSN2 package after transferring from HPC cluster
I'm creating spatial models using the package SSN2 in R on an HPC cluster, then transferring the fitted SSN2 models in .rds format to my local drive to choose the best fitted model. Once I transfer the models over, I try to calculate RMSPE using loocv() but receive the error "Unable to locate required distance matrix." In R on the cluster, the loocv() function runs fine. However, I would like to run that function on my local drive rather than the cluster. My question is, why is my fitted model missing the distance matrix when transferred as an .rds file? How can I run the loocv() function on my local drive rather than the cluster without having to refit the model? These models take multiple days to run on the cluster, so I don't want to have to re-run each model every time I want to calculate a model-fit statistic.
I have tried fitting the model on my local drive and then running loocv(), which works.
Here is the code I run on the cluster to fit each model then run loocv(). In this case, loocv() runs fine:
library(SSN2)
library(readr)

SSN1 <- ssn_import("/models/SSNFolder/LSN1.ssn", 
                   include_obs = TRUE, predpts = c("s1a1"), overwrite = TRUE)


ssn_create_distmat(
  ssn.object = SSN1,
  predpts = c("s1a1"),
  among_predpts = TRUE,
  overwrite = TRUE
)



B1 <- ssn_lm(
  formula = MAXTEMP_C ~ SHADE + AIRTEMP + WDR + BFI + ASPECT + FLOW, 
  ssn.object = SSN1,
  tailup_type = "exponential", 
  taildown_type = "spherical", 
  euclid_type = "gaussian",
  additive = "afvArea",
)

write_rds(B1, "/models/outputs/partbmodels/B1.rds")

loocvB1 <- loocv(B1)

write_rds(loocvB1, "/models/outputs/partbmodels/B1loocv.rds")

Here is the code I run on my local computer for fitted models to calculate loocv():
B1 <- readRDS("/B1.rds") # (a fitted SSN2 model from the cluster)
loocv(B1)

# Returns "Error: Unable to locate required distance matrix"

I have tried importing the original SSN file, then calculating the distance matrix (following the first two functions of the first code chunk), importing the fitted model, then using loocv(). This doesn't work either.
Here is a reproducible example using the SSN2 example data:
# Run on R in HPC cluster:

library(SSN2)
library(readr)


copy_lsn_to_temp()
temp_path <- paste0(tempdir(), "/MiddleFork04.ssn") 
 
mf04p <- ssn_import(temp_path, overwrite = TRUE) 

ssn_mod <- ssn_lm(
  formula = Summer_mn ~ ELEV_DEM,
  ssn.object = mf04p,
  tailup_type = "exponential",
  additive = "afvArea"
)

loocv(ssn_mod)

write_rds(ssn_mod, "/ssn_mod_test.rds")



## Now move ssn_mod_test.rds over to a local drive and run in R:


ssn_mod_test <- readRDS("/ssn_mod_test.rds")


loocv(ssn_mod_test)

# same error should appear

